# VBA Excel Resume duplicate count without changing previous duplicate count after restart count

Tags: excel, vba

I have been stuck with this for weeks not sure how to do it.

1. I have a code that will count duplicate and restart the count at the same 
   time when weekday = 1 which is Monday
2. Weekday value is in column sheet 2, column B9
3. Column I = shows the duplicate count value (1,2,3,4,5)
4. Column Q to state that the value is duplicate

My Issue is how do I change the code so that it will resume the duplicate count on weekday 2,3,4 and 5  and would not change last week duplicate count:-

1. So let's say last week duplicate count is weekday 1 =1,weekday 2= 2, weekday 
   3 =3 so this week if there is another 2 duplicate.
2. It will count as 1 ,2 for this week ***not*** continue the duplicate count 
   from last week as 4, 5.
3. I assume it needs to be tied to column Q so when it's not empty it wont 
    change the previous duplicate count?

Below is the code:-

```
Sub restart() 'TO restart on monday

Dim LastR As Range, x As Long

If IsEmpty([h5]) Then Exit Sub
Set LastR = [i5]
If Not IsEmpty(LastR) Then Set LastR = Range("i" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
x = Range("h" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If x < LastR.Row Then Exit Sub
If Sheet2.Range("B9").Value = 1 Then 'when weekday =1
With Range(LastR, Range("i" & x))
    .Formula = "=mod(countif(h$" & .Row & ":h" & .Row & ",h" & .Row & "),5)+" & _
            "if(mod(countif(h$" & .Row & ":h" & .Row & ",h" & .Row & "),5)=0,5,0)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
End If

End Sub
```

[Desired Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gkkw.jpg)

Comment: Do you have a visual representation of desired output? I find it hard to interpretate your question without it.

Comment: HI there @JvdV My apologies I should have included an image for better understanding. I have attached an image for your viewing. the image shown is the targetted result

Comment: @JvdV, please do let me know if you need me to clarify more. Thank you for helping

Comment: what if all this can be done without VBA. Would you rather have that?

Comment: really? if it works I dont mind really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I've done:

- Cell `B2` has formula `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,D:D,"<"&D2,E:E,E2)+1`
- Cell `C2` has formula `="Weekday "&WEEKDAY(D2,2)`
- Cell `E2` has formula `="WEEK "&WEEKNUM(D2,2)`
- Cell `F2` has formula `=IF(B2>1,"Duplicate,"")`
- Drag down the formulas

[image]

Offcourse you'll need to reference your columns according to your data.

To automatically put in formulas when some new data is added to your list there are many ways, but a simple one could be:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Dim X As Long, LR As Long
With ActiveSheet
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
For X = 2 To LR
    If Cells(X, 2) = "" Then
        Cells(X, 2).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(A:A,A" & X & ",D:D,""< ""&D" & X & ",E:E,E" & X & ")+1"
        Cells(X, 3).Formula = "=""Weekday ""&WEEKDAY(D" & X & ",2)"
        Cells(X, 4).Value = Date
        Cells(X, 5).Formula = "=""Week ""&WEEKNUM(D" & X & ",2)"
        Cells(X, 6).Formula = "=IF(B" & X & ">1,""Duplicate"","""")"
    End If
Next X

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Calculate
End Sub
```

Paste this macro under the worksheet you are using. And again, change references of columnnumbers to your own.

Comment: Thank you so much @JvdV it works. I do wonder however would there be a way of making this process automatic So I don't have to drag the formula the whole column?

Comment: @NorLina, yes offcourse. There are multiple options, however you'll have to use VBA in that case. For example, look into a sheets change event targeting column A as its range. On adding data you could make it automatically add the formulas (and even the date of data-entry).

Comment: Thanks again @JvdV , I will look into it and experiment. So sorry if I have asked an unreasonable question as I am really new in this.

Comment: Also is there a way for me to upvote ur answer not sure how?

Comment: Thank you so much no words can express my gratitude. Upvoted your answer and ticked as answer.

Comment: HI there @JvdV so sorry to disturb you, not sure what I did wrong , but when I paste in the data column more than 100 row  theres an error . Run-time error '-2147417848(80010108) : Method 'Formula' of object 'Range' failed . Is there a way for me to change the formula so that it can handle more then 100000 row of data?

Comment: @NorLina, in the first sentence you mention a 100 rows, in the last one a 100.000. Which one is it? And more important, when exactly do you get this error? But please first try changed code above (disabling and enabling change events while running the code). Regards.

Comment: my apologies,  What I meant there is, when I tested copy paste 100 data  the error.  Run-time error '-2147417848(80010108) : Method 'Formula' of object 'Range' failed appeared that is just for testing purposes however I would love it if it can handle 10, 000  data at a time.  The error only appears when I try copy paste anything above then  60 rows of data in the A column.  I  tried the enabling and disabling events and it worked. but now trying to figure out how to make the process faster as  it will take  30 minutes to loop 900 rows of data.

Comment: To make it faster you could also turn of automatic calculation and screenupdating. See updated answer. Good luck with it all :)

Comment: Thank you so much that solved all the issues :)  I have learned a lot from you. Thanks again